# Django: Trouble with logging user using Bootstrap login.html

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I'm using Django 3.0.2 + Boostrap. I have created a `registration/login.html` page. The contents of this page are shown below.

The page renders correctly and most of it works OK. However, I am unable to login to my website through this page. I keep getting `Your username and password did not match. Please try again`. I can login to the `admin` website without any issues if I use the same username/password. I am not sure what is wrong with my `login.html`. Any ideas?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password did not match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account does nohave access to this page. To proceed,please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="p-5">

                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Welcome Back!</h1>
                </div>

                <form class="user" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputUserName" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" value="Login">
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
                </form>

                <hr>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" href="register.html">Create an Account!</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Contents of views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout


def logout_view(request):
    """Log out user from the website."""

    logout(request)
```

Comment: you need to share your codes for view

Comment: change  {% if user.is_authenticated %} to  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}

Comment: @ruddra what more would you like to see?

Comment: @bmons Thanks. I tried it but same problem.

Comment: try to provide `name="username"` and `name="password"` to your input type text and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` types are missing the name attribute. As per the [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname) docs:

> A string specifying a name for the input control. This name is
>   submitted along with the control's value when the form data is
>   submitted.

So the name is submitted with the form. But what if there is no `name` attribute?
Same Documentation explains:

> Consider the name a required attribute (even though it's not). If an
>   input has no name  specified, or name is empty, the input's value is
>   not submitted with the form.

So your username and password are not sent to the backend.

You need to provide the name attributes to your input types.

```html
<form class="user" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputUserName" placeholder="Username" `name="username"`>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password" name="password">
       </div>
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block" value="Login">
       <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
</form>
```

It is front-end issue, not particularly related to Django.